# Spring Boot accessing MongoDB - multiple records/documents update from rest api endpoint

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am very new to SpringBoot and MongoDB. I was trying to create a simple service to use for retrieve data from MongoDB. Used the spring tutorial "https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/" to model it out. So I will put my question exactly to match to this tutorial code.

I was able to use the REST endpoint "http://localhost:8080/people" with GET to retrieve all data and POST to input data as json.

What I am trying to achieve is to use the same REST endpoint with POST to insert multiple records/documents into MongoDB in one call which is erroring out.
Errored JSON Input:

```
[{  "firstName" : "Smith",
    "lastName" : "Joe"
},
{   "firstName" : "Smith",
    "lastName" : "Jane"
}]
```

Single record JSON which is success:

```
{   "firstName" : "Smith",
    "lastName" : "Joe"
}
```

While going thru forums, I could see most of the suggestion were to use insertMany(), but that would need me to explicitly handle that post request. Was looking for any expert opinion to do the same with any Out Of Box capability of spring boot data.
Any help with your expert opinion is appreciated, please pardon if the question is very basic, just that I am very new to this..

Comment: Can you add Controller class for /people specially POST method

Comment: Sure Ashish, let me try that and update back. But one qn though, if I have to write controller to handle the POST with multiple records would that mean mean I have to write it for GET as well or that will use the default?

Comment: I think your GET call is already fetching multiple record. so no need to write GET calll for Multiple records

Comment: Hi Ashish, I was able to post multiple records after adding a Controller class with List added. But eventually I had to write GET method as well since I believe with a controller I overrided the default Spring Boot impl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in Controller method you are defined Simple object as an argument, you just define List of object `(List<Object>)` as an argument instead of Simple Object.

Example:

```
@PostMapping
public void save(List<People> peoples){
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Devendra Kumar. I was able to post multiple records after adding Controller with List object.